# What is the probability of exactly two accidents on at least one day of a week, in case of 7 indistinguishable accidents per week

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 7 accidents (all are indistinguishable i.e we care only about whether accident happen or not, not the details of it) happen in a week.  What is the probability of exactly two accidents on at least one day of a week.

My solution is given below

$$
\frac{1}{13 \choose 6} \Bigg[{7 \choose 1}{10 \choose 5} - {7 \choose 2} {7 \choose 4} + {7\choose 3} 4 \Bigg] = 0.681
$$

I used the equation that number of ways $r$ balls can be arranged in $n $ cells in ${n+r-1 \choose n-1}$ distinguishable ways.

Is it correct ?

Comment: I cant follow your reasoning. Can you explain why this formula should be correct?

Comment: @Nurator included the information.

Comment: In order to have an unambiguous way of answering, we need to know how the accidents themselves are distributed.  In a similar "balls-in-bins" problem, we might say "take a ball, throw it at the bins so that it randomly lands in one of the bins uniformly at random.  Then take another ball and throw it in as well, so that where that ball lands is uniformly distributed and independent to the previous."  As alluded to below, it is very uncommon for the $\binom{13}{6}$ outcomes to be equally likely in practice, making this an uncommon assumption.

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes in practice uniform at random assumption might not hold. But in my case, I assume it. Thanks

Comment: I think the word "probability" should have some unusual meaning, so that your solution was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of all possible distributions of accidents is (stars and bars method) $${13\choose 6}$$

The number of all possible distributions of accidents if 2 happend on monday is $${10\choose 5}$$

The number of all possible distributions of accidents if 2 happend on monday and 2 on thuesday is $${7\choose 4}$$

The number of all possible distributions of accidents if 2 happend on monday and 2 on tuesday and 2 on wednesday   is $${4\choose 1}$$ So the naswer is, by PIE: $$P={{7\choose 1}{10\choose 5} 
  -{7\choose 2} {7\choose 4}+{7\choose 3}{4\choose 1}\over {12\choose 6}}$$

So, your answer maches with my answer.

Comment: why it is downvoted ?

Comment: That makes the wild assumption that each of the possible outcomes where you treat days as distinct and accidents as indistinct are equally likely to have occurred.  Do you really think it is equally likely that all seven accidents occur on monday as it is that one accident happens each of the days?

Comment: Despite the fact that we *say* the accidents are indistinguishable, under most sensible interpretations of this problem and problems like it, it makes the most sense to treat this behind the scenes as each of the accidents (*or balls for a balls-in-bins problem*) as being distinct so that we can work within an equiprobable sample space.  The probability of occurrence isnt simply "*total number of good outcomes divided by total number of outcomes.*"  That *only* works if the outcomes are equally likely to have occurred, which the problem statement does *not* imply that the outcomes you use are.

Comment: @JMoravitz Will you provide a correct solution?

Comment: @Aqua linked a duplicate above.  Note the usage of $7^7$ as the sample space size, rather than $\binom{13}{6}$

Comment: @JMoravitz. $7^7$ indicates that accidents are distinguishable right ?

Comment: @Shew if you want to think of it that way, yes, but you can always after the fact choose to partition the resulting sample space so that you "forget" that they were indistinguishable.  This is just like how if you want to talk about the problem where we toss several coins and ask how many total tails we got (*by treating the coins as indistinguishable*) we might choose to first treat the coins as distinct, looking at the $2^n$ equally likely outcomes, find probabilities with that, and use those probabilities when describing the probabilities had the sample space been of size $n+1$

Comment: The probability of zero tails out of $n$ flips of identical fair coins is not equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$... it is $\frac{1}{2^n}$.  Yes... the coins are indistinguishable, but no that doesn't mean that we avoid the sample space where they are distinguishable.  The sample space where they are distinguishable is far too useful.  All that the tails being indistinguishable means is that we can't tell HHHTTT apart from HTHTHT in the end and so our events must group them together.

Comment: @JMoravitz I got your point.  So the correct answer is to use $7^7$ instead of ${13 \choose 6}$ Thanks.